# deleting the temp files to disable excel auto-recovery option

Tags: c#, excel

While force-closing the excel application, I am getting the auto-recover option which I want to avoid.
On checking the temp files, an asd file gets generated while closing the excel. But it still is not handy.

I tried checking forum solutions in C# but none is working.

Is it possible that if I try to delete the temp files, the auto-recovery option will get disable? Is there any other way for this approach?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please provide what you have tried so far (i.e. code that you have tried so far). My initial question would be, why are you **force-closing** excel? Surely you can do a clean exit? If you really have to do this, have your tried switching off `Auto Recovery`?

Comment: Where and how are you force-closing excel? Why do you want to avoid the auto-recovery option? This is normally supposed to be of help. Is this for your personal use or something you're forcing on users of software you're writing? (it is generally a bad idea to make applications work differently from what users know and expect)